# variable is not acting independently when using multiple copies of same angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to create a directive with 2 radio button binding with `update` variable.  Now I planned to use the same directive in once again.  Now the problem is the scoped variable `update` is not acting independently.

Below is the mock example I have created,

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        template: '<div><span>A new directive</span>'
                    + '<input name="updated" type="radio" ng-model="con.isUpdate" ng-checked="con.isUpdate" />'
                    + '<input name="updated" type="radio" ng-model="con.isUpdate" ng-checked="!con.isUpdate" />'
                    + '</div>',
        controller: controller,
        controllerAs: 'con'
    };

    function controller ($scope) {
        $scope.isUpdate = true;
    }
});
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div my-directive></div>
        <br/>
        <div my-directive></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Running the code snippet will give a clear picture of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `radio` inputs have the same name so the browser is "grouping" them if you will and applying updates to the radios based on name.

An easy way to fix this is to pass the name to the directive to apply to the radios, or (as shown below) create different directives.

```
function Directive(name) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        template: '<div><span>A new directive</span>'
                    + '<input name="' + name + '" type="radio" ng-model="con.isUpdate" ng-checked="con.isUpdate" />'
                    + '<input name="' + name + '" type="radio" ng-model="con.isUpdate" ng-checked="!con.isUpdate" />'
                    + '</div>',
        controller: controller,
        controllerAs: 'con'
    };

    function controller ($scope) {
        $scope.isUpdate = true;
    }
}

myApp.directive('myDirective', new Directive('updated'));
myApp.directive('myDirective2', new Directive('updated-alt'));
```

Comment: ahhh! my bad.. didn't noticed it.  Thanks